# Python requests parameters not going through

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm trying to make a post request to Quizlet following their OAuth flow from these instructions `https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/authorization-code-flow`. I'm running into a problem where on Step 2, I have to make a post request with a token I generated from their server, but I'm not having success passing in the token to the url. I know it was generated correctly, but I'm having trouble passing it in and not getting a `400` response.

More directly, my question is, is there another way of including the `grant_type` and `code` parameters that I'm trying to pass in through the url in the post request such as passing them in through the header of the post request? I've looked at the documentation for `requests` but I've had no luck.

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    state = request.args.get('state')
    print("code is " + code)
    r = requests.post("https://api.quizlet.com/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + code)

    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the required headers `Authorization`, `Content-Type`.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import _basic_auth_str

client_id = 'YOUR CLIENT ID'
secret = 'YOUR CLIENT SECRET'
code = 'CODE FROM STEP 1'

headers = {
    'Authorization': _basic_auth_str(client_id, secret),
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
r = requests.post('https://api.quizlet.com/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}'.format(
    code), headers=headers)

print r.status_code
print r.content
```

Comment: Ok I fixed a small problem in the code. Also I moved the 3 variables you need to update at the top. After running it I got 200 and an access token. Let me know if it works for you.